# Bootstrap Combobox Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

## The Background

I have the following HTML document:

```
<!-- file: index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>

    <!-- Plugins CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-combobox.css">

</head>

<body class="one-page fixed-header">
    <div class="page-box">
        <div class="page-box-content">

            <h3>Form 1</h3>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="combobox-container" id="employee-name-box">
                    <label for="addScheduleLoc">Location: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select class="form-control combobox location" name="addScheduleLoc" id="addScheduleLoc" required>
                        <option value selected="selected">---Select Location---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="combobox-container" id="employee-name-box">
                    <label for="addScheduleTier">Tier: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select class="form-control combobox tier" name="addScheduleTier" id="addScheduleTier" required>
                        <option value selected="selected">---Select Tier---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            
            <hr>
            
            <h3>Form 2</h3>
            <div id="changeScheduleModalBody" class="content">

                <div class="combobox-container" id="employee-name-box">
                    <label for="chScheduleLoc">Location: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select class="form-control combobox location" name="chScheduleLoc" id="chScheduleLoc" required>
                        <option value selected="selected">---Select Location---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="combobox-container" id="employee-name-box">
                    <label for="chScheduleTier">Tier: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select class="form-control combobox tier" name="chScheduleTier" id="chScheduleTier" required>
                        <option value selected="selected">---Select Tier---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- .page-box-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- .page-box -->

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>

    <script src="js/testJavascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

There is an AJAX call to a server which retrieves some data after the page has loaded and puts the data into a variable and is used to populate the comboboxes. There are multiple comboboxes that should contain the same information (eg. All comboboxes with class "location" should contain the same list of locations). I have simulated this in the following javascript file. Please note that the initialization of the comboboxes must happen first because I may need to update the contents of the associated `<select>` element after the combobox is initialized.

```
//file: js/testJavascript.js
var options = {
    locations: "<option id='1'>London</option><option id='2'>Los Angeles</option><option id='3'>Sydney</option>",
    tiers: "<option id='1'>Upper</option><option id='2'>Middle</option><option id='3'>Lower</option>"
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox({
        bsVersion: '3'
    }); //This statement cannot be moved. 
    
    $('select.location').append(options.locations);
    $('select.tier').append(options.tiers);
});
```

---

## The Problem

The problem that I'm running into is after I append the options to the `<select>` elements, the comboboxes aren't updated to show the most recent information. I realize that if I call `$('.combobox').combobox({...});` after options are added, the combobox will be correct. But I may need to update the information in the comboboxes after the comboboxes are initialized the first time.

---

## The Question

How can I get the comboboxes to update after I add options to the corresponding `<select>` tag and after they have already been initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research and fiddling around, I found that the following code works to refresh the combobox. (using the [issue shown here](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/issues/25))

```
$('select.location').each(function(){ //need to run in .each to refresh all the elements
    $(this).data('combobox').refresh();
});

$('select.tier').each(function(){ 
    $(this).data('combobox').refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your combobox using the following code :

```
$('select.location', 'select.tier').data('combobox','refresh');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried this, however the comboboxes remain empty/don't update.

Comment: I actually found that using this method sets `$('select.location').data('combobox')` to equal `'refresh'`. The select element is no longer set to the combobox data.